# Remove quotes from XML value

Tags: xml

I know that there is already questions similar to this ones but sadly any of them have been able to answer my question.
Probably because my lack of understanding of XML

I have this piece of code

```
<action name="TeleportToAction"
            key="teleportto"
            minParams="0"
            maxParams="0">
<mapping key="type" value="teleportto"></mapping>
<mapping key="target" isRemainder="true"></mapping>
</action>
```

What I want is that the "target" value does not have extra quotes, for example: "luck" will be only luck.
I have tried using & quote; and translate by any of them have worked for me, is there any way to do this?
Any solution you can give, please try to keep this simple because I have no experience working with XML before

Comment: It would be helpful if the example XML that you posted contained the unwanted value, such as `"luck"`. It doesn't help if you post content and then describe something that isn't in the example content leaving us guessing/assuming what you mean.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for you comment, but I am no sure what do you mean for contain the unwanted value.
All what I now is that "target" will receive an string and that I need to remove the " " in the string, the value of this is random and since my code need to pass a test, all I know is that the result is wrong

Comment: Luck does not appear in the example XML

Comment: Oh! That is what you mean, well I could have explained better that it was an string that the "target" can take(just an example)and from which I need to remove the " "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the *identity template* in combination with the `translate` function on the `text()` nodes.

```
<xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="translate(.,'&quot;','')" />
</xsl:template>    

<!-- identity template -->
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

If you only want to apply this to the `key="target"` element, replace the first template with:

```
<xsl:template match="*[@key='target']/text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="translate(.,'&quot;','')" />
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer. It actually works!
But I have a question more, is there a way I can specify which "target" to match?
For example, if I have other <actions>, I only want to match the ones from "TeleportTo.."

Comment: Yes, there is a way. Use the following match rule for the template: `match="action[contains(@name,'TeleportTo')]/*/text()"`. This rule will match the `text()` nodes of all elements which are children of `action` elements with a `@name` attribute which contains the text "TeleportTo".